# scrapy use the same session to access website

Tags: python, session, cookies, scrapy

I want to use the same session to access some urls. After reading the docs about cookie, I do like this below:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(self.getUrl, meta={'cookiejar': 0}, callback=self.downloadPic)

def downloadPic(self, response):
    yield scrapy.Request(self.vcodeUrl, meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']}, callback=self.getAndHandlePic

def getAndHandlePic(self, response):
    # handle picture, not the point here
    pic = self.handlePic(response.body)
    yield FormRequest(self.postUrl, formdata={'a':a, 'pic':pic}, meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']}, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
   # do process source code
```

Can anyone explain why that doesn't work?

Comment: can you check if cookie is enabled in setttings.py file (HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=True)

Comment: @MrPandav I have done it, but doesn't work.

Comment: parameter for cookie would be COOKIES_ENABLED= True (which is enabled by default) 
also , did you try with COOKIES_DEBUG=True and see if same cookie session is used for all http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=cookie#cookies-debug

Answer (score 0):

well, the simplest and forceful way is open the firebug, to see what exactly are in the request headers, then copy all the value, except things like cookie that will change, that needed you set it in the program.
Be like the browser.